# Stata: Convert date, quarter to year

Tags: time-series, stata

I have a time series dataset with quarterly observations, which I want to `collapse` to an annual series. For that, I need to transform my date variable first.

It looks like

```
. list date in 1/5

    +--------+
    |   date |
    |--------|
 1. | 1991q1 |
 2. | 1991q2 |
 3. | 1991q3 |
 4. | 1991q4 |
 5. | 1992q1 |
    +--------+
```

Hence, to `collapse`, I want `date` (or `date2`) to be 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1992 etc.

Once I have that, I could use `collapse` or `tscollapse` to turn my dataset into annual data.

Comment: Why exactly was this question migrated from CrossValidated?

Comment: It has nothing to do with statistics. It's a programming question.

Comment: It's about a statistical software package - so "nothing" is clearly not the right term here. The distinction between statistics and programming statistics is also rather arbitrary. As a result, there's now some questions relating to Stata/R/Matlab/Gauss etc in CrossValidated and some are here in Stackoverflow. So in essence, this creates two separate stack exchanges with partially overlapping content. I really don't see the point in that.

Comment: This is a purely a programming question about data management and this is a much better place for it. CV does have some questions like this in the archives, but the recent trend is to send them to SO. Unfortunately, this is not explained well anywhere except in the meta site for CV, where is all but invisible to the casual user. Questions about how to use *statistical* method X or accomplish *statistical* goal Y with package Z are more on-topic at CV. In contrast, Statalist policy is not to distinguish between these use cases.

Comment: +1. I strongly support the idea that this post belongs on SO, not CV. There are many Stata-linked threads on both, but anything purely about the language belongs here. If you like the idea of a Stata-based list there is also Statalist, which is also supported by most of the most active Stata people on CV and SO. However, if you wish to pursue discussion, that is really for meta, not here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// create some example data 
. clear all

. set obs 5
obs was 0, now 5

. gen date = 123 + _n

. format date %tq

// create the yearly date
. gen date2 = yofd(dofq(date))

// admire the result
. list

     +----------------+
     |   date   date2 |
     |----------------|
  1. | 1991q1    1991 |
  2. | 1991q2    1991 |
  3. | 1991q3    1991 |
  4. | 1991q4    1991 |
  5. | 1992q1    1992 |
     +----------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way is just to remember that years and quarters are just integers. A little consultation of the documentation and a little fiddling around yield

```
  . gen Y = 1960 + floor(Q/4)
```

as a conversion rule to get years from Stata quarterly dates. Formatting year as a yearly date is then permissible but superfluous.